# Buffer size problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

This is a math question that I am thinking about which arose from trying to implement a circular buffer in computing. The question can be best phrased using a warehouse analogy.

Suppose that I have a distribution center that contains bricks. Every morning a single truck carrying N bricks arrives at the center. Every afternoon trucks carrying M bricks take them away. The M trucks will keep going all afternoon until there are less than M bricks in the distribution center.

The question is, given N and M, how much space (measured in bricks) does the distribution center require?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might finish the day with $M-1$ bricks.  The truck arrives bringing $N$, so you now have $N+M-1$.  That is how much space you need.  You could argue for subtracting $\gcd (N,M)$ instead of $1$.  If you start with no bricks and really follow what you said you won't get closer to $M$ at the end of the day than $M-\gcd(N,M)$.  As an example, let $N=10,M=4$.  You start with $0$, get $10$, and ship $8$, leaving $2$.  Then you get $10$ which gives $12$, so you ship all $12$ and are empty.  The cycle repeats and we have $\gcd (10,4)=2, 10+4-2=12$ is the room you need.